# activate ng-repeat using ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, q, angularjs-ng-click

So basically I created this menu using ng-repeat where it displays a field of objects inside an array.
Then when I click on one of these displayed fields I want to make another ng-repeat that will push the other ones below. I only want to activate this second ng-repeat on click and also undo if the user clicks again. Meaning, ng-repeat will only occur after the user clicks on a button.

Any ideas how I should execute this?

```
<div ng-repeat="collection in library" ng-click="setCollection(collection)">
          <li class="list-group-item">{{collection.Collection}}</li>
</div>
```

And here I have some code from the JS file

```
$scope.library = [
            {
                Collection: "Harry Potter",
                value: false,
                books: [
                    {
                        book: "Sorcerer Stone",
                        value: false                        
                    },
                    {
                        book: "Goblet of Fire",
                        value: false,
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                Collection: "LOTR",
                value: false,
                books: [
                    {
                        book: "Two Towers",
                        value: false                        
                    },
                    {
                        book: "Return of the King",
                        value: false,
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];

        $scope.setCollection = function(collection){
            collection.value = !collection.value;
        };
```

So if the user clicks on the collection it ng-repeats all the books right beneath the collection name. 
If clicks again on the same collection all of them hide again.
If clicks on a book after clicking on the collection I want it to set the value to !value. Setting the value to true or false must work on collections and on books.

Thank you :)

Comment: Show us your code. You can apply a class to display the item, or use ng-show to show it by demand.]

Comment: I just added some code and some more words to explain my case.

Comment: Check my solution, see if it helps @N.Car

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a demo just like you want, you only need to change a little bit of code.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Welcome varun';
  $scope.mainMenu = [{
    title: 'A',
    subMenu: ['A1', 'A2'],
    subMenuDisplay: false
  }, {
    title: 'B',
    subMenu: ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
    subMenuDisplay: false
  }, {
    title: 'C',
    subMenu: ['C1', 'C2'],
    subMenuDisplay: false
  }];

  $scope.toggle = function(menu) {
    menu.subMenuDisplay = !menu.subMenuDisplay;
  };
}
```

```css
.menu {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 30px;
  background: grey;
  border: 2px solid black;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.subMenu {
    min-width: 50px;
    min-height: 30px;
    background: magenta;
    border: 2px solid black;
    cursor:auto;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div>
    {{title}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class='menu' ng-repeat='menu in mainMenu' ng-click='toggle(menu)'>
      {{menu.title}}
      <div class='subMenu' ng-repeat='sub in menu.subMenu' ng-show='menu.subMenuDisplay' ng-click='$event.stopPropagation()'>
        {{sub}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: It's almost perfect. But how would you do it if you just want to toggle it when you click on the first menu? I mean, you click on A and it shows, you click again on A and it should hide. Clicking on the sub menu items should only work for opening submenus and not to toggle like it is now.

Comment: Can you check it again, I have updated this demo and now clicking on A shows/ hides it's submenu but clicking on submenu does not have any effect

Comment: Ah yes!!! Works perfectly fine! But what does this ng-click='$event.stopPropagation()' perform?
I would like to add some other function on this ng-click and I wouldnt be able, would I?

Comment: This is what stops submenu from being clicked.
You can read more about this in my blog http://logic24by7.com/angularjs-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault/

Also can vote for my answer if this is correct

Comment: yes, you can use semicolon (;) as a separator
OR 
you can call a function and pass $event as 1st argument
ng-click="myFunc($event, myOtherParams)"
and in function myFunc(event, myOtherParams){ event.stopPropagation();  your code}

Comment: Imagine I want to do an unknown number of ng repeat, Any recommendations on how to procceed? 
In the situation above we know there's only two levels, collection and books of that same collection. But what if its an unknown number of levels?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have:

```
<ul ng-hide="someVariable">
    <li ng-repeat="foo in bar"></li>
</ul>
```

And then wherever the ng-click happens do this:

```
<button ng-click="showStuff()">Show Hidden Stuff!</button>
```

And inside your controller do this:

```
$scope.someVariable = true;
$scope.showStuff = function(){
    If($scope.someVariable){
        $scope.someVariable = false;
  } else {
        $scope.someVariable = true;
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe doing something like this:

```html
<div ng-controller="TestController as ctrl">
  <ul class="menu">

    <li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.menu.items">
      <a ng-click="ctrl.openSubmenu(item)">{{item.label}}</a>

      <ul class="submenu"
          ng-if="item.submenuIsOpen">

        <!-- Submenu content right here -->

      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
 </div>
```

```js
// On your controller
var vm = this;

// Set the menu object with items
vm.menu = {
  items: [
    {
      label: 'Item 1',
      submenuIsOpen: false
    },
    {
      label: 'Item 1',
      submenuIsOpen: false
    }
  ]
}

// Then create the open submenu function
vm.openSubmenu = function(item) {
  item.submenuIsOpen = !item.submenuIsOpen;
}
```

You can use $scope as well, as @codeninja pointed out.